# Error: 'webView' undeclared

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to display the webpage 
http://johnbridge180.com/Boarders.html
I can't quite get this to work I only have one error: "'webView' undeclared". Here is the code for the app:
WebViewController.h:

```
    //
    //  WebViewController.h
    //  Boarders
    //
    //  Created by John Bridge on 5/2/11.
    //  Copyright 2011 Bridge and co. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface WebViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIWebView *displayWeb;
    }
    @end
```

WebViewcontroller.m:

```
   //
   //  WebViewController.m
   //  Boarders
   //
   //  Created by John Bridge on 5/2/11.
   //  Copyright 2011 Bridge and co. All rights reserved.
   //

   #import "WebViewController.h"


   @implementation WebViewController
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       displayWeb.userInteractionEnabled = true;
       [displayWeb loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc]            initWithString:@"http://www.johnbridge180.com/Boarders.html"]]];
[super viewDidLoad];
   }
   @end
```

Hope you guys can help Thank You!!

Comment: What line does it show the error on?  What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you presented here is fine. However from the error I assume that you are trying to call the 'displayWeb' variable with the 'webView' name. Searching thought your .m file for 'webView' and you'll find it.

Also try do clean your project if that doesn't work.

Your code is also leaking (a lot). Please review the [cocoa memory management basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)!

Answer (score 0):

there are a few problems here...

You are not creating your url and request correctly, they would not be cleaned up correctly the way you were doing it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       displayWeb.userInteractionEnabled = true;
       [displayWeb loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithUrl:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.johnbridge180.com/Boarders.html"]]];
       [super viewDidLoad];
   }
```

That way you are creating an autoreleased url, and request.

Please give a little more information where it says webView is not declared.